# Calculate $\frac{2\cos40^\circ-\cos20^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this task i.e. calculate this expression without using calculator, in terms of known values for angles such as 30,60,90,180 degrees :).

$$\frac{2\cos40^\circ-\cos20^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}$$

Thanks.

Edit: 
Special thanks to David H. The problem was, indeed, unsolvable, until I discovered a mistake in my textbook and corrected it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This looks like a job for trig identities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\cos 40^{\circ}=\cos (60^{\circ}-20^{\circ})=\sin 20^{\circ} \sin 60^{\circ}+\cos 20^{\circ} \cos 60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin 20^{\circ}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 20^{\circ} $

Comment: This hint is possibly misleading because it does not lead to a solution of the proposed problem. In fact, the proposed problem is technically unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{2\cos\pars{40^{\circ}} - \cos\pars{20}^{\circ} \over \sin\pars{20}^{\circ}}:
     \ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large{2\cos\pars{40^{\circ}} - \cos\pars{20}^{\circ} \over \sin\pars{20}^{\circ}}}
> ={2\cos\pars{40^{\circ}}\cos\pars{60^{\circ}} - \cos\pars{20}^{\circ}\cos\pars{60^{\circ}}
> \over \sin\pars{20}^{\circ}\cos\pars{60^{\circ}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\cos\pars{40^{\circ}}
> -\
> \overbrace{\bracks{\cos\pars{60^{\circ}}\cos\pars{20}^{\circ} + \sin\pars{60^{\circ}}\sin\pars{20^{\circ}}}}^{\ds{=\ \cos\pars{40^{\circ}}}}\ +\ \sin\pars{60^{\circ}}\sin\pars{20^{\circ}} 
> \over \sin\pars{20}^{\circ}\cos\pars{60^{\circ}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\tan\pars{60^{\circ}} = \color{#66f}{\large\root{3}} \approx 1.7321
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle\cos60^\circ=\frac12, I=2\cos(60^\circ-x)-\cos x=2\cos(60^\circ-x)-2\cos60^\circ\cos x$

Using [Werner's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), $\displaystyle I=2\cos(60^\circ-x)-[\cos(60^\circ-x)+\cos(60^\circ+x)]$

$\displaystyle\implies I=\cos(60^\circ-x)-\cos(60^\circ+x)=2\sin60^\circ\sin x$

Here  $\displaystyle x=20^\circ$